# Program allowing to send group messages with a specific pattern

Tags: excel, email

I am wanting to write a program(probably VB) that allows the user to send emails to all on the list(pre-stored in MS Excel or txt) at one time. In the first line of the body of the email content, I would like to write something like "Dear xxx" where xxx is the name relevant to the person that this email will be send to. The reason that I wanna do this is because it may save time if there are a large number of receivers and I don't need to modify "xxx" for each one of them and the program will do it for me automatically once the associated email address is selected from the list. I tried to implement it inside of Excel using built-in VBA but I couldn't find a method to get "XXX" replaced automatically, and Outlook would open multiple windows for different receivers. Any ideas on how to achieve it? I feel like I need a loop to go over the list but i have no idea how to do it. I am fine with writing a new program instead of modifying Excel. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like that:

```
Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
For Each xx In Range("A1:A5")
    Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    aEmail.Subject = "Test"
    aEmail.HTMLBody = "Dear <b>" & xx.Value & "</b><p>I sent to you ..." & Range("B7").Value
    aEmail.To = xx.Offset(0, 1).Value
    aEmail.display
    'Send Mail
    ' aEmail.Send
Next
```

If you want to use model you can simply compile in HTML format inside some HIDDEN cells in the XLS...

This sub write to 5 people (from A1:A5 the name, from B1:B5 the email) a text composed (Dear XXX) plus a standard part (Cell B7).

Comment: Thx for the info. What if I just want to pick some of them from the list? Your code seems to always select all by default if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Yes, preselected list. You can add a Select Case or some IF. Depend of your workbook structure. Where you store this List ? You want to change list, witch criteria you use ? Where are stored ?